# Understanding calls to python class instance methods from within the class

Tags: python

Consider the following class: especially the

```
__repr__()
```

method:

```
class PowerClustering(object):

def __init__(self, kClusters, max_iterations=20, init_mode="random"):
    self.k_ = kClusters
    self.max_iterations = max_iterations

@property
def k(self):
    """Get the number of clusters."""
    return self.k_

@property
def maxIterations(self):
    """Get the number of clusters."""
    return self.max_iterations

def __repr__(self):
    return "%s: k=%d maxIterations=d " %(self.__class__, self.k)
```

This works fine:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "%s: k=%d maxIterations=%d" %(self.__class__, self.k, self.maxIterations)

test_pic output: <class 'pyspark.mllib.clustering.PowerClustering'>: k=2
```

But adding in the call to

```
self.maxIterations
```

in the ***repr**()*  does not work:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "%s: k=%d maxIterations=%d" %(self.__class__, self.k, self.maxIterations)
```

Here is the output now:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    in __repr__
    return "%s: k=%d maxIterations=%d" %(self.__class__, self.k, self.maxIterations)
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not JavaMember
```

But both of those methods:

- k
- maxIterations

are declared the same way. Why do they end up being treated differently when invoked?

Comment: Are you passing something else besides an `int` to `max_iterations`?

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me:

```
p = PowerClustering(10,30)
In [723]: p.maxIterations
Out[723]: 30

In [724]: p
Out[724]: <class 'PowerClustering'>: k=10 maxIterations=30
```

I tried your version in the OP